# How do I avoid embedding the connection string in a Dynamics CRM 2011 SQL report?

Tags: sql-server, report, dynamics-crm-2011

I have used BIDS (VS2008) to develop a SQL-query report for a Dynamics CRM 2011 instance.  This runs OK in VS preview but I'm puzzled as to how to deploy it because the RDL file has the database connection string hard-coded in it.  Surely this should not be present in the RDL, because that will make it impossible to promote the report through DEV, UAT and into LIVE?  I suspect that I have missed something fairly basic but if anyone could advise me, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that when you suck it in through the Report Manager, there's a mechanism in there that will change the connection string in the report to that of the target system.  I haven't dug deep to try and figure it out for sure but I've not had a problem deploying rdl files before.  It just automagically works.

Answer (score 2):

When you deploy a report into CRM it will take any connection strings and make sure they are pointing to the correct CRM database. This can cause problems if you are using another external database but there are work arounds. But for a simple report that only uses CRM data you don’t have to do anything

Comment: OK, got it, thanks.  I had been confused by a report which worked in SQL Server not working when imported into CRM.  In case anyone else gets the problem:

Comment: OK, got it, thanks Kevin and @John. I had been confused by a report which worked in SQL Server not working when imported into CRM. There are two relevant and related issues, so to help anyone else with the problem: (1) In SSMS, filtered views don't return any results unless you use integrated security and a CRM login with appropriate permissions; whilst in CRM the non-filtered views are not available. (2) The report import in CRM will replace the data source in the .RDL file with one that points at the CRM data.  Thanks again both.